# Python/postgres: Any advantage to converting mxDateTime to built in datetime objects?

Tags: python, datetime, postgresql, psycopg2

Some code I am inheriting uses Python's psycopg2 module to return mxDateTime objects from Postgres database queries. I am guessing this behavior is for historical reasons, but wondering if there there is another explanation.
Given that I already have an mxDateTime dependency via the the large library I have inherited, is there any advantage to converting to the built in datetime data type before operating on these dates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's big a reason to not change it that is not historical. Built in python timestamps are often only 32-bit.

Postgresqls timestamp:

> min value 4713 BC
>
> max value: 5874897 AD

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-DATETIME-TABLE

Python's:

> classmethod date.fromtimestamp(timestamp)¶
>
> ... It’s common for this to be restricted to years from 1970 through 2038. Note that on non-POSIX systems that include leap seconds in their notion of a timestamp, leap seconds are ignored by fromtimestamp().

http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.fromtimestamp

On windows 7 with Python 2.5:

```
>>>> date.fromtimestamp(0)
datetime.date(1969, 12, 31)
>>> date.fromtimestamp(-1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: timestamp out of range for platform localtime() function
```